# Create a batch file which perform delete the Internet cache

Tags: batch-file

Please help in creating a batch file which perform the below tasks

It will delete the TEMPORARY INTERNET FILES, COOKIES, CACHE of a diiferent system in network by providing the assetID/IP.

Kindly help

Comment: That _should_ be totally impossible. It violates all security ideas ever thought up. But then again: we are talking about MS-Windows here...

Comment: [do you know what google can do for you ?](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/clear-privacy-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-safari/) Use it locally. you cannot do it from distance, unless you allow it. Which is a good news for potential hackers.

Comment: Thanks Arkascha for reverting. Why i am saying this because if our domain account locked out due to multiple password provided/stored in cache of that system. (a case of frequent account lock out issue) then we can unlock it by clearing the cache, cookies and temp files.